# Can you derive a new column based on the value of 2 or more columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Essentionally I have 2 columns that are Strings. I've tried this to return a `TRUE` `FALSE` response but its not working:

```
DFz['Pass'] = DFz[(DFz['Inflation Bond'] != 'Y') & (DFz['Bond Coupon'] != 'ZERO COUPON')]
```

I get the error:

```
Wrong number of items passed 18, placement implies 1
```

Then I tried this:

```
DFz['test'] = [(DFz['INFLATION_LINKED_INDICATOR'] != 'Y') & (DFz['CPN_TYP'] != 'ZERO COUPON')]
```

But got this error:

```
Length of values does not match length of index
```

Sure there are many blanks in the columns but they are the same lengths.

:( Please help this noob.

Comment: Please show a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It is not at all clear what your initial dataframe looks like or what result you want afterward.

Comment: Try using `and`, not `&`.  `&` is bitwise operator, `and` is boolean operator in Python.